# firefox extension content script not reload for multiple page?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

i work with firefox addon sdk, i develop an extension and i have problem with content script i want to include content script in multiple page in same website whitout reload of script, with pagemod we can include script for all match pattern :

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    include : "*.mywebsite.com",
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScriptFile : "myscript.js"
});
```

but i don't find the way to load myscript.js in multiple page (for example : mywebsite.com/page1 or mywebsite.com/page2) whitout reload myscript.js ?

Comment: why? it will load when you visit any page hosted at *.mywebsite.com .why do you want it to not load?

Comment: yes he is loaded whitout problem but he is **reloaded** for each page in website !  myscript.js need only one load...

Answer (score 0):

pageMod will load the script every time a tab/window is opened, page is refreshed or url changes and matches the requirements in the include.

you can try the tabs api. From the setup I threw together real quick, it will reload if the page is refreshed, a url is manually entered, but not when a user clicks a link.

in the "index.js" file

```
var self = require('sdk/self');
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.on('ready', function (tab) {
    var url = tab.url;
    if(url.indexOf('https://www.facebook.com') != -1){
        tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: ['./index.js']
        });
    }
});
```

in the content script file I had a timer outputting to the console.

```
var cnt = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    unsafeWindow.console.log(cnt);
    cnt++;
}, 1000);
```